# Exclude elements from a hash based on contents of nested hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following Ruby hash...

```rb
{
  "Aura"=>{"eyes"=>403, "moon"=>134, "burst"=>75, "psych"=>249},
  "Power: Verdure"=>{"max"=>4, "min"=>1}, 
  "Power: Creature"=>{"max"=>3, "min"=>1}, 
  "Iris"=>{"ice"=>208, "sky"=>220, "aqua"=>206, "deep"=>215, "dusk"=>229, "hide"=>213}
}
```

I want to remove any element whose hash has `max` and `min`. The value of max/min doesn't matter. Just the fact that they exist.

Meaning the hash above would turn into...

```rb
{
  "Aura"=>{"eyes"=>403, "moon"=>134, "burst"=>75, "psych"=>249},
  "Iris"=>{"ice"=>208, "sky"=>220, "aqua"=>206, "deep"=>215, "dusk"=>229, "hide"=>213}
}
```

How would I remove those elements?

Comment: [`Hash#delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if), or [`Hash#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Hash.html#method-i-reject) in combination with [`Hash#key?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) should get you there

Comment: Try `h.reject { |_,v| (['max', 'min'] - v.keys).empty? }`. See [Hash#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject). To modify the hash in place use [Hash#delete_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if). Note that `delete_if` returns the new hash, even if it is unchanged, whereas [Hash#reject!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject-21) returns `nil` if no change is made.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, this can readily be solved by application of `Hash#reject` and `Hash#has_key?`.

```rb
data = {
  "Aura"=>{"eyes"=>403, "moon"=>134, "burst"=>75, "psych"=>249},
  "Power: Verdure"=>{"max"=>4, "min"=>1}, 
  "Power: Creature"=>{"max"=>3, "min"=>1}, 
  "Iris"=>{"ice"=>208, "sky"=>220, "aqua"=>206, "deep"=>215, "dusk"=>229, "hide"=>213}
}

pruned_data = data.reject { |k, v| v.has_key?("min") && v.has_key?("max") }
```

If it processes better in your brain, we can `#select` only hashes that *don't* contain both of those keys.

```
pruned_data = data.select { |k, v| !(v.has_key?("min") && v.has_key?("max")) }
```

There are more clever ways, but this is a very straightforward problem that seems in need of a straightforward solution.